# Math operation in SQL

Tags: mysql

could somebody help me with a working SQL-Statement that would do this?

> In the table "postmeta" all values from the column "meta_value" should
>   be multiplied with 1,19 if "meta_key" is "*price*"

And - if possible - the results should being rounded up or down to the next full number (eg: 210 instead of 210,20)

Maybe i should say that i am not a coder - i just try to find my way to solve a problem i have with my woocommerce.
Kind regards axel

Comment: Are you trying to do a select or an update?

Comment: Thanx for helping.
Please delete my post.

Comment: What if it's meta_key != 'price'? Then what?

Comment: @AxelLauer — There is a link that will allow you to delete your own question just under the question.

Comment: Hallo Soren, thanx for trying to help a "dumbass" like me but the "warm welcome" of Barmar shows me that this is not the place for me.
Best wishes Axel

Answer (score 0):

Write a SELECT statement first, and develop the expression to do the math operation:

```
SELECT p.meta_value               AS old_val 
     , ROUND(p.meta_value*1.19,0) AS new_val 
     , p.meta_key
     , ...
  FROM postmeta p
 WHERE p.meta_key = 'price'
```

Once we verify that the results of our expression for new_val is what we want to store, and the rows being returned are the rows we want to update, then ...

```
UPDATE postmeta p
   SET p.meta_value = ROUND(p.meta_value*1.19,0)
 WHERE p.meta_key = 'price'
```